# Arranging columns in sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check if the column headers are in their right positions ( I have declared the actual column headers as constant values) and if they are not move them around to their right positions.

I'm new to VBA and when I tried it out with the basic `For` loop and `Select Case`, I realised the code was too long. I was thinking if there is another perhaps a simpler way to do it.

Below is a sample of the code I tried:

```
Sheet4_Last_RowNum = WorkingSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet4_Last_ColNum = WorkingSheet.Cells(Label_RowNum, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For icol = 1 To Sheet4_Last_ColNum
    Select Case WorkingSheet.Cells(Label_RowNum, icol).Value

    Case "WkVersion"
        Sheet4_WkCol = icol
        If Sheet4_WkCol <> Sheet4_ActualWk Then
            Sheet4_WkValue = WorkingSheet.Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_WkCol), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_WkCol))
        End If
    Case "MPA"
        Sheet4_MPACol = icol
        If Sheet4_MPACol <> Sheet4_ActualMPA Then
            Sheet4_MPAValue = WorkingSheet.Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_MPACol), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_MPACol))
        End If
    Case "Location"
        Sheet4_LocCol = icol
        If Sheet4_LocCol <> Sheet4_ActualLoc Then
            Sheet4_LocValue = WorkingSheet.Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_LocCol), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_LocCol))
        End If
    End Select
Next icol

With WorkingSheet
    If IsEmpty(Sheet4_WkValue) = True Then
    Else
        .Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_ActualWk), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_ActualWk)) = Sheet4_WkValue
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Sheet4_MPAValue) = True Then
    Else
        .Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_ActualMPA), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_ActualMPA)) = Sheet4_MPAValue
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Sheet4_LocValue) = True Then
    Else
        .Range(Cells(headerRow, Sheet4_ActualLoc), Cells(Sheet4_Last_RowNum, Sheet4_ActualLoc)) = Sheet4_LocValue
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Why are you using `If... Else` when nothing is in your `If...Then`? Just change to `If Not IsEmpty() Then` or `If IsEmpty() = False Then`

Comment: But I would like to also see your constants. If you make them type Long then you could possibly line that up with the `iCol` value and validate that way

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs i shall change it If not IsEmpty(). I get what u mean. My constants are in this format: Public Const Sheet4_ActualWk = 1
Public Const Sheet4_ActualMPA = 2
Public Const Sheet4_ActualLoc = 3